# Why is chart.js canvas not respecting the padding of the container element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, chart.js

I am using Chart.js with a simple line chart but the width and height properties calculated by Chart.js seem to be based on the total width and height of the parent element ignoring padding.

```js
var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true
};

var data = {
    labels: ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx1 = document.getElementById("mychart1").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx1).Line(data, options);
```

```css
.container {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.js"></script>


<div class='container'>
    <canvas id='mychart1' class='child'></canvas>
</div>
<br>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='child'>test</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whw90pkh/)

The second container and child shows the behaviour I am expecting. Is this a bug with how Chart.js calculates the width and height of the canvas or am I making a styling mistake?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I also needed a responsive canvas and had this issue. This was my fix:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Since Chart.js scales the canvas to the width of the container, ignoring the padding, I just wrapped the canvas in a `div`. The `div` scales to the container with padding, respecting the padding, and then the responsive Chart.js `canvas` scales to the `div`.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way to work around the issue.

Comment: Nice simple fix. Works great!

Comment: This solution is simple and help me out to make the doughnut chart bigger

<div style="width: 170%;left: -35%;position: relative;">
      <canvas id="doughnutChart"></canvas>
</div>

Answer (score 4):

I too googled for this problem and ended up with a simple solution.

I added `height` so that it automatically adjust the width accordingly and show it in a nicer way. If u really want you could add `width` too. The `canvas` element is part of `HTML5`.

It does not allow you to input values with `px`. So ignore that and just type tha numerical value u need.

```
 <canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your jsfiddle example change the `responsive` attribute to false:

```
var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: false
};
```

The previous setting added a additional 30px to both the height and width when you inspect the element using Chrome dev tools. Because of the size of the canvas it should not be problematic when it comes to resizing of the canvas.

**[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/whw90pkh/2/)**

Comment: We actually need it to be responsive. The behaviour I am after is a responsive width with a static height, so responsive true and maintain aspect ratio false. I can make it work by wrapping it in an additional containing div without padding, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgx37rhy/) but this seems like a work around only necessary because Chart.js does not calculate the canvas dimensions correctly.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is to use 
`.container {box-sizing: border-box;}`

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the  in  and then used this CSS.

```
.chart-container {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:2%;
  width:96%;
}
```

This keeps it padded from the edges and responsive. I used 2% but you can use whatever percentages suit your layout.

Answer (score -1):

"If for example, you wanted all charts created to be responsive, and resize when the browser window does, the following setting can be changed:"

`Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;`

"Now, every time we create a chart, options.responsive will be true."

Source: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Comment: Please add an explanation of what the OP is supposed to do with this line of code. This will for both the OP and future people give a solid possible answer

Comment: The chart is already set to be responsive. This doesn't fix the problem and could cause problems if there are other charts that shouldn't be responsive.