# Remove chart.js canvas padding and margin

Tags: css, angular, chart.js

I am using chart.js to show a line chart in an Angular component. The code does not have any padding or margins added for the chart. I added styling to set the padding and margin to zero both in the create the chart in the .ts file and in the style sheets and nothing makes any difference. When I inspect the element in Chrome developer mode it does not show any padding or margins, so I think the styling is internal to chart.js. Below is a screenshot with the chart element highlighted in Chrome developer mode.
[image: Screenshot of the chart in Chrome developer model]

As you can see, there is a margin or border on the left, bottom and right of the chart canvas element, but strangely not at the top. The spacing between the Y-Axis labels and the left of the chart are especially bad when viewed on a mobile phone so I really need to remove it. I have spent hours setting every element I can think of to have 0 padding and 0 margins and trying different changes to the code and style sheets and searching through other articles on the Internet including Stackoverflow but none of them seem to answer this specific question.

I also tried adding box-sizing:border-box; to the div container containing the chart but it did not make any difference, i.e. as suggested in this article:
[Why is chart.js canvas not respecting the padding of the container element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162810/why-is-chart-js-canvas-not-respecting-the-padding-of-the-container-element)

Here is my chart configuration:

```
      this.myChart = new Chart("chartCanvas", {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: labelVars,
          datasets: datasets
        },
        options: {
          elements: {
            point: {
              radius: 0
            },
          },
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            enabled: width > 640
          },
          hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
          },
          legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
            }
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'week',
                tooltipFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
              },
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: ''
              },
              ticks: {
                autoSkip: true,
                padding: 0,
                maxTicksLimit: this.getTickLimit(),
                maxRotation: this.getRotation(),
                minRotation: this.getRotation()
              },
              gridLines: {
                display: false,
                offsetGridLines: true
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: ''
              },
              ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 6,
                beginAtZero: false
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
```

Here is the current html:

```
    <div class="chartContainer">
        <canvas *ngIf="displayChart" id="chartCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
```

And here is the current css:

```
  #chartCanvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .chartContainer {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: left;
    align-self: left;
    align-content: left;
  }
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: can you share your chart.js confiig?

Comment: I added my chart.js config. Thank you for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your chartjs *config*, you just have to set the `padding` of the chart.js *config*.

> ***Info:*** *Offset's in the canvas **cannot** be altered with css, since the chart is "drawn" on it.*

*(**details:** [in the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/))*

***For a example:***

```
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        ...
        plugins: {       
            ....
        },
        scales:{
            x: {
                ticks:{ padding:0 }
            }
        },
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried the padding:0 in the past but added it again to doublecheck and it did not make any different. The documentation says the default is 0. I added my chart config in the article above so you can see the current settings.

Comment: This helped me remove the left-side spacing of the horizontal bar chart.